# "fulfill or achieve or accomplish my goal"?

Tags: word-choice

I know "achieve my goal" is correct.

Is it good to say "fulfill my goal" or "accomplish my goal"?

Thanks!

Comment: If relevant for 'correctness', note that "fulfill" is American spelling; British spelling is "fulfil".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. All three are perfectly idiomatic normal English.

> Angela **fulfilled her goal** of becoming a professional pianist.
>
> Joseph **accomplished his goal** of getting into Harvard.
>
> In order to **fulfill my goal** of becoming an astronaut one day, I will need to study physics and then become a professional pilot.

Answer (score 1):

"fulfill"means you achieve the thing that you had hoped for ,promised ,wanted :

An Arizona couple fulfilled their dream of getting married in Tahiti.

"achieve" means to succeed in doing something good or getting the result you

wanted,after trying hard for a long time :

Women have yet to achieve full equality in the workplace.